# Getting job repository URL in Jenkins build plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am writing a build notification plugin for Jenkins. The SCM repository URL (SCM being git to begin with) contains useful information I'd want to get to in my code. Being the beginner with the Jenkins API that I am, I am having trouble figuring out how I should go about retrieving the job's repository location. Is this doable, and if so, how?

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this, I've been looking through the JavaDocs and plugin source codes, without success. I know how to do it using xml but that way is veery convoluted, slow and error prone. There must be a way of doing `scm.getUrl()` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer! The method needed is not defined in the abstract [SCM](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/scm/SCM.html) class, but by the classes which extend it. So when you call `project.getSCM()` you have to then cast it to the type of SCM that you actually have (GitSCM, SubversionSCM, etc.).

I am developing my plugin to work with Subversion, so I looked through the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java) for the Subversion Plugin, and found the method `getLocations` which returns a `ModuleLocation[]` which contains information on all the SVN repositories in that project. Simply looping through the `ModuleLocation[]` and calling `getSVNURL()` gets me the information I want. I can then play around with the [SVNURL](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNURL.html) as needed (`toString()` gives me the full repository path).

In your case, for Git, the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java) shows that there is a method called `getRepositories()`, which returns a `List<RemoteConfig>`. Look through the RemoteConfig [source code](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/RemoteConfig.html) to see which method gets you the information you need. (I believe `getURIs()` will do the trick).

Answer (score 3):

The repository is available in the config.xml of the job.

http://[jenkins server]/job/[job]/config.xml

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get URL of SVN repository for a particular job using following code:

```
String jobName = manager.build.project.getName()
def job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(jobName)
def svnScm = job.scm
def svnLocation = svnScm.getLocations()
def svnURLstr = svnLocation[0].getSVNURL().toString()
```

Perhaps it will be useful to someone.